# Click on checkbox button, will display textfield and submit button, click on submit button should disable the checkbox button

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledged" ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)"></td>
<td>
<span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
<div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
    <input type="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)"> Submit </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
</div>
```

When I click on checkbox button, the text textfield with submit button will be popped up. After entering the comments on textfield, when the user clicks on submit button, the checkbox should get disabled. Can anyone give me some inputs on this? How to disable the checkbox button, once when I click on Submit button?

```
$scope.saveAlert = function(alert) {
    $scope.alert.acknowledged = true;
    /*alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true;*/
    var alertUrl = $incidentsUrl+ "/" +alert.alertForIncident.incidentID+"/alerts/"+alert.alertID;
    $http.put(alertUrl, alert).then(function(result) {
        alert.acknowledgeInProgress = false;
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have the ng-click on the checkbox just set the ng-model to ng-model="alert.acknowledgeInProgress" the check box will set that to true and will trigger the showing of the input and buttons.

```
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledgeInProgress" ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)"></td>
    <td>
    <span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
    <div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
        <input type="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)"> Submit </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: In JS Controller, should I need to modify anything?

Comment: You did not show your controller so I don't know but from what I see no.